# printing characters "in a row" from "for loop" in php

Tags: php, for-loop, echo

Is there a way to print characters in a row using for loop with php?
When i try nor `echo` nor `print_r` prints them in a row, instead prints in a column.

/case 1/Prints characters in a singe row: 1 2 3. (the same with echo)

```
<?php 
print_r("1 ");
print_r("2 ");
print_r("3 ");
?>
```

/case 2/Prints characters in a column, automatically starting new line. (the same with echo)

1

2

3

```
<?php 
for($i=1; $i<=3; $i++){
    print_r($i); 
}
?>
```

I want to print characters in a single row from `for loop`.

Comment: _I want to print characters in line_??

Comment: I am sorry for writing here, most probably nobody would ever notice. My conclusion after more than two years with php and jQuery is that their place is in the bin comparing with Python. Already 5h i am trying to make a simple sript for "typing skills improovement" , i.e. characters random input and user input. With pyton 5y ago i did this in some 15-30 min. With javascript and php nothing works after 5h of efforts.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a string variable outside of your loop and append characters in the loop.

You can then echo or print the string once the loop has finished.

Comment: Thank you, seems i stop thinking. This is elementar.

Answer (score 1):

try a simple print instruction

```
for($i=1; $i<=3; $i++){
    print $i." "; 
}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, i did not notice this function in php documentation

Comment: welcome Bro , if this solved you problem please set it as best answer by clicking valid mark ;)